# Email user new link to create a password

Tags: asp.net, security, passwords, forgot-password

For Password Recovery my vb.net application send an email to the user with a link in the following format.

`http://<password-reset page url>?id=<userid>&tpr=<times Password Reset>&time=<time when the link was generated>`

`Times Password Reset` is the number of time the user has used a password reset link to reset the password. It's value in the database and the value in query string are matched. To ensure the same password reset link cannot be used twice to reset the password. 
`Time` is use to check that not more than 24 hours have been passed before the link is used. 
And `userid` is used to identify the user.

If all the conditions matches, the user is prompted to change his/her password.
All the fields in the in the encrypted with AES.

I wanted to know if this method is secure?

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer: No.

Forget all the parameters you use in the URL. Just generate one random, non-guessable string (UUID for example) and put it in the URL as parameter. Then send that URL to the user via the email adress you have stored for him. Store the UUID together with all the parameters you have in your URL now in your database. When the user clicks the link, validate all parameters (timestamp, and so on) and let him set a new password.

Se also the [OWASP Cheat Sheet on Password Reset](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Forgot_Password_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: This is actually a pretty good solution and i use it myself. +1